# How to fetch list of all ConsumerGroup from the Kafka Server(Not Zookeeper) in Java

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Is there any Java Api in Kafka that gives me the list of all the consumer groups along with the topic/partition from which they are consuming 
Also, is there any way that I can fetch the zookeeper list from the kafka server side .
Note: I am able to fetch the above information from the Zookeeper. But I want to fetch it from Kafka Server.
Could you please help me out on this!!

Thanks In Advance!!

Comment: Did you found any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `kafka-consumer-groups.sh` command. This will list the consumer groups.

```
./kafka-consumer-groups.sh --list --bootstrap-server localhost:9092
```

When you open that script, you will see the following.

```
if [ "x$KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS" = "x" ]; then
    export KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS="-Xmx512M"
fi

exec $(dirname $0)/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer "$@"
```

For windows,

```
"%~dp0kafka-run-class.bat" kafka.admin.ConsumerGroupCommand %*
```

In Github, you can see the code for [ConsumerGroupCommand](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/33d06082117d971cdcddd4f01392006b543f3c01/core/src/main/scala/kafka/admin/ConsumerGroupCommand.scala).

I guess, you can use those API.

*P.S.*

I don't know about your other question :

> Also, is there any way that I can fetch the zookeeper list from the kafka server side

(I think no, maybe?)